# Java Collect Joining Custom Function

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've created the following function:

```
private BooleanExpression createExpresionByJoiningOf(List<BooleanExpression> expresionsForEachStatus) {
        BooleanExpression inAnyOfSelectedStatus = expresionsForEachStatus.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < expresionsForEachStatus.size(); i++) {
            inAnyOfSelectedStatus = inAnyOfSelectedStatus.or(expresionsForEachStatus.get(i));
        }
        return inAnyOfSelectedStatus;
    }
```

The booleanExpression list that it is being pass to the method have been created by stream function:

```
    List<BooleanExpression> expresionsForEachStatus = originalList.stream()
     .map(statusToBoleanExpresion)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My question is how would you create a custom Collector to join the BooleanExpressions of that list. So, I would have something like this:

```
originalList.stream()
  .map(statusToBoleanExpresion)
  .collect(joinedBooleanExpresion());
```

Comment: Why not use `Collectors.reducing()` for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a method that returns an ***`identity`*** implementation of `BooleanExpression` for the `or` operation and then simply perform a `reduce` such as:

```
return expresionsForEachStatus.stream()
        .reduce(BooleanExpression.identity(), BooleanExpression::or);
```

Comment: Or just `.reduce(BooleanExpression::or).get()` considering that the original code didn’t support empty lists either.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good solution posted by Naman, you can skip the full reduction by using `anyMatch`, as (it seems to me) the logic of `createExpresionByJoiningOf` is to return `true` if any of the expressions is truthy:

```
boolean anyTrue = originalList.stream()
                      .map(statusToBoleanExpresion)
                      .anyMatch(exp -> exp.getValue()); //replace with right getter
```

This avoids the unnecessary iterations that your for-loop (or `reduce`) goes over after a `true` values has been found

Comment: @Puce I probably don't get that. `createExpresionByJoiningOf` is not being used with a method reference or a different expression evaluated repeatedly... Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hmm, I was in the context of JavaFX where there is a BooleanExpression binding class with an `or` method, but I might be wrong: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanExpression.html